# Typescript/Angular 2 - filter out objects that do not include a specific string property

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I'm creating a filter in my angular application that removes all objects that do not contain specific string property within a nested array.

for example... I have an array that looks like this:

**JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"example1",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "pink",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"example2",
    "categories": [
      "blue",
      "black",
      "purple",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"example3",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "black",
      "white"
    ]
  }
]
```

When you click a button the function will only show the objects that contain the specified category.

**Something like...**

```
<button (click)="filter('red')">filter by category</button>

filter(category) {
  // only show objects that contain (category) string.
}
```

Any help would be great cus I just haven't managed to crack it.

Hope this is enough info

Comment: Did you know that arrays have "filter" method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`array.filter`** and **`array.includes`** with **`!`**

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"example1",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "pink",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"example2",
    "categories": [
      "blue",
      "black",
      "purple",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"example3",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "black",
      "white"
    ]
  }
];


const r = data.filter(d => !d.categories.includes('red'));
console.log(r);
```

So you need to change your filter function as,

```
filter(category) {
  const result = data.filter(d => !d.categories.includes(category));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan. So what would my filter() function look like?

Comment: Thanks very much. Will try this and accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to filter out your record.

> **Component**

```
var arr = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"example1",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "pink",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"example2",
    "categories": [
      "blue",
      "black",
      "purple",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"example3",
    "categories": [
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "black",
      "white"
    ]
  }
];


function filterData(colorName) {
    arr.filter((item) => {
      return item.categories.indexOf('white') !== -1;
    });
    console.log(arr);
}
```

> **HTML**

```
<button (click)="filterData('red')"></button>
```